# Как с помощью random.choice выбрать одну картинку из папки

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot, случайные-числа

Не хочу отдельно прописывать каждую картинку, можно ли сразу из папки выбирать?
Пишу бота в телегу, через телегбота

```
img_list = [r'C:\Users\Star\Desktop\telegbot\photo\photo1.jpg', r'C:\Users\Star\Desktop\telegbot\photo\photo2.jpg', r'C:\Users\Star\Desktop\telegbot\photo\photo3.jpg', r'C:\Users\Star\Desktop\telegbot\photo\photo4.jpg']
    
    img_path = random.choice(img_list)
    bot.send_photo(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, photo=open(img_path, 'rb'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`os.listdir(path)` даёт список всех файлов в папке.

```
img_list = os.listdir(r'C:\Users\Star\Desktop\telegbot\photo\')
```

Возможно, потребуется отфильтровать только жипеги.